# Numbering an array as one single equation LaTeX

Tags: numbering, arrays

I've looked around at various sites and tried switching between `array`/`eqnarray` but don't seem to be able to get the effect I would like. I want to simply give an array I have one single equation number. I would also like to know just to make sure, how to give each equation a number within an array.

The equation I have is the following:

```
$$
\begin{array}{lr}
N_{x,sk} = k_{sk}\left(\frac{t_{sk}}{b_{sk}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et} \;\;
N_{x,st} = k_{st}\left(\frac{t_{st}}{b_{st}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}
\end{array}
$$
```

Could someone please help provide examples where I would have these equations showing one equation number and then also an example with two separate ones please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `eqnarray` environment instead of `array`, you can add `\nonumber` to any lines you don't want numbered. If you *don't* do this, every line will be numbered.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
N_{x,sk} &=& k_{sk}\left(\frac{t_{sk}}{b_{sk}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et} \nonumber \\
N_{x,st} &=& k_{st}\left(\frac{t_{st}}{b_{st}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}
\end{eqnarray}
```

(Just remove the `\nonumber` from the above to get the second example.)

Comment: Agreed. In the answer, I use `eqnarray` as the "vanilla" built-in multi-line equation alignment environment, but `align`, `IEEEeqnarray`, etc. are much better choices in general.

Comment: Please consider reading Peter Grill's answer, as use of `eqnarray` is *not* recommended.

Answer (score 22):

I would recommend you use the `equation` environment if you want a single equation for an entire `array`.

However, since this construct does not really seem to need an `array`, I would recommend using the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package, with which you can use `\nonumber` to selectively disable an equation number.

[image]

### Notes:

- Use of `eqnarray` is not recommended as per [\eqnarray vs \align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196).
- Also you should not use double dollar signs for display math as per [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)
- The math spacing in you array example was not correct. This has been corrected in the example below.

### References:

- An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}\noindent
Using \verb|equation| with \verb|array|:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r@{}l}
    N_{x,sk} &{}= k_{sk}\left(\frac{t_{sk}}{b_{sk}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}\\
    N_{x,st} &{}= k_{st}\left(\frac{t_{st}}{b_{st}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
%
Using \verb|align|:
\begin{align}
    N_{x,sk} &= k_{sk}\left(\frac{t_{sk}}{b_{sk}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}\\
    N_{x,st} &= k_{st}\left(\frac{t_{st}}{b_{st}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}
\end{align}
%
Using \verb|align| with \verb|\nonumber|:
\begin{align}
    N_{x,sk} &= k_{sk}\left(\frac{t_{sk}}{b_{sk}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}\nonumber\\
    N_{x,st} &= k_{st}\left(\frac{t_{st}}{b_{st}}\right)^{2}\bar{Et}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `{r@{}l}` exactly mean in `\begin{array}{r@{}l}` ?

Comment: @NumberFour: `@{}` eliminates the inter column spacing that is usually there with `tabular` and `array`. Try removing it to see the difference. The `r` and `l` set the columns to be `l`eft and `r`ight aligned.

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this -- using equation and array? How would you allow for natural spacing of fractions? My fractions, integrals, etc that are generally larger are getting squished to one line making them hard to read using the equation and array as in the first example.

Comment: @EricBringley: Without seeing the specific issue you are referring to it is hard to give you advice. I would suggest you ask a new question (and reference this one if it is relevant) and include  fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: Sorry, @PeterGrill. Will continue browsing other questions before opening a new question. Thanks for the reply.