# How to assign only one number to an equation with multiple lines?

Tags: equations, arrays, eqnarray

As is shown in my code, I used eqnarray but got two numbers. So I tried the method [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83353/numbering-an-array-as-one-single-equation-latex) by using equation and array instead. But I got error messages: "Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\max): `c' used." and "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."

As for the second error, I checked [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Extra_alignment_tab_has_been_changed_to_%5Ccr) but was still confused. The incorrect example in that link has different numbers of "&" across lines, but my code does not have such a problem.

My code is as follows.

```
          \documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
          \usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsaddr, amssymb, graphicx, dsfont,}
          \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
            \DeclareMathOperator{\ima}{Im}
         \newcommand{\namedthm}[2]{\theoremstyle{plain}
        \newtheorem*{thm#1}{Theorem #1}\begin{thm#1}#2\end{thm#1}}
            \usepackage{float}
     \usepackage{tabularx}
      \usepackage{array, makecell}

          \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
                             {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}




                \begin{document}

  \begin{eqnarray}
  \max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\} &&\quad \mbox{ and } \\
    \quad \max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}.&&
    \end{eqnarray}\bigskip
   


  \begin{equation}
          \begin{array}
        \max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\} &&\quad \mbox{ and } \\
         \quad \max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}.&&
     \quad \max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}.
       \end{array}
  \end{equation}
       

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is what you want. If not, you can use images to illustrate the effect you desire. This will help facilitate our communication.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\}  & \text{and} \\
\max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}. &            \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\}  & \text{and} \\
\max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}  & \text{and} \\
\max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}. &            \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: better to use aligned than array, so it's in display math

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest you employ either a `split` or an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment. That way, that material will be typeset in display-style math mode, and you'll obtain more generous line spacing than using an `array` environment would offer by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} & \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\} , \text{ and} \\
  \max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} & \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\} \,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
   
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max\{0, \alpha_g-\beta_g\} & \leq d_g \leq \min\{\alpha_g, 1-\beta_g\} , \\
\max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} & \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}, \text{ and} \\
\max\{0, \alpha_b-\beta_b\} & \leq d_b \leq \min\{\alpha_b, 1-\beta_b\}\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
       
\end{document}
```